# Serializing objects bigger than 2MiB to Json in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, kendo-ui

We are currently doing Performance tests to determine, if Kendo UI is fast enough for our needs. For that we need to perform tests with a large database (~150 columns and ~100,000 rows).

Table rows should be read by a Kendo UI Grid using ajax calls, which return the data as a json string. With our test data (random strings of 3-10 chars) this works for up to ~700 result rows per request. More, and we hit maxJsonLength, which is already set to `Int32.Max-3`.

We **are not** planning on displaying that many rows per page, but there might be binary data attached to the rows. That data could, even with 20 rows, easily go above the 2 MiB restriction implied by having to use an `Int32` to set the max size.

So is there any way to serialize objects with a length bigger than 2M?

Comment: Do you actually need to fetch the binary data when you fetch the rows, or could you defer that? What *is* the binary data? (If it's images, for example, then it would make more sense to perform separate requests for that anyway...)

Comment: I sure hope we can do that and I can't think of a way around this right now anyway. The Problem is: Telerik products are not exactely cheap and we want to have tested the possibilities as good as possible, before purchasing a licence for additional developers ;)

Comment: When sending large requests, we've compressed the string on the server and decompressed it back into json on the client using something like LZMA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are now using the Json lib from http://www.newtonsoft.com to serialize the objects. It is not bound by the `web.config` settings and can handle Json requests of unlimited length afaik.

Answer (score 2):

JSON isn't really designed to transfer large binary data. If you want your UI to be fast and snappy you should try splitting larger objects into smaller ones and also removing binary content from the json.

For example, you can refactor the content of json to only carry a link to the binary resource. If that binary resource is *actually* needed on screen you can perform a separate request. In fact you can perform requests in parallel: e.g. load json and display the content. Load first *N* entries with binary data and display it. Don't load the rest as it will slow down your page render time.

Comment: Basically we want to test the limits of the kendo ui approach before purchasing any more developer licences. The way you described is the best way to go for the actual final product obviously, but I'm talking about a test scenario here ;)

Comment: Your test is bound to fail apriori and does not reflect the speed of the product you trying to buy. I have no idea what kendo is, but the test looks incorrect to me. Such test will crash a browser for which you should blame the test itself and not the browser. I'd suggest to re-think your test strategy.

Comment: kendo ui is a framework to produce javascript and html code, sparing us the necessity to create that ourselves. what we want to know is: how much data can it actually handle before being unacceptably slow. Of course we'll keep in mind, that this is not representative for a real situation. It is only supposed to give us a hint about the actual performance and if it **could** handle more if necessary.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd try do display as little as possible anyways, in which case any descent framework should cope with data volume. IMO, nobody *really* likes or needs to see huge amount of data. I'd try to summarise data first and present a quick summary. I'd also add ability to drill-down into the data. Think about Twitter or Facebook.